# A way to determind the window size and turn javascript/jquery code on if true and off if not true

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been looking around, trying to figure out a way to turn on jquery code like media in css where it's based on the screen size.

I have seen several solutions/questions where they are asking for how to just one-time fire off, this is something I want to turn on as in normal, like make the jquery code available and used above 1024px and not just one time which

```
if ( $( window ).width() > 1024 )
```

will do, but I need it to like the media in css.

css example for what I'm thinking of but i would like it for javascript/jquery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width: 1024px)" href="style.css" />
```

I have this jquery code running and I want it to only be activated/turned on and works when the window size is above 1024px and turned off when the window size is below 1024px.

There's nothing wrong with the jquery code I'm just trying to explain my situation, as I can't figure out the keywords, and can't seem to find other questions with an answer.

EDIT:

As answers have been on, is this you want me to use, but it's only firing once it's resized, that's not what I am thinking of as it would be just duplicate.

But I want it to run like normally run, not one-time fire/call each time it's resized.

If i remove the resize and if statement, it's running as it should but i want it to only do that, once the screen size is above 1024px and keep running, is it possible? like with the hasclass("resize") on a certain div, i tried to put it on body, but it didn't quite work out.

```
$( window ).resize( function ()
{
    if ( $( window ).width() > 1024)
    {
        $( "#main-nav-box" ).click( function ()
        {
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "clicked" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "in" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "open" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "closed" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "closed" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "in" );
            $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "open" );
            setTimeout( function ()
            {
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "in" );
            }, 250 );
        } );
        $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).click( function ()
        {
            if ( $( window ).scrollTop() === 0 )
            {
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "clicked" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "open" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "closed" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "open" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "closed" );
                setTimeout( function ()
                {
                    $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "in" );
                }, 250 );
            } else if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > 0 && $( window ).scrollTop() > $( ".jumbotron" ).height() )
            {
                if ( !$( "#main-nav" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                {
                    $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
                }
                if ( !$( "#main-nav-box" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                {
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
                }
                if ( !$( "#scrolltop" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                {
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
                }
                $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "clicked" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "open" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "closed" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "open" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "closed" );
                setTimeout( function ()
                {
                    $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box-menu" ).addClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box-menu-overlay" ).addClass( "in" );
                }, 250 );
            }
        } );


        if ( $( window ).scrollTop() === 0 || $( window ).scrollTop() < $( ".jumbotron" ).height() )
        {
            if ( !$( "#main-nav" ).hasClass( "scrolledtop" ) )
            {
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
            }
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
            $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
            $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
            setTimeout( function ()
            {
                $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
            }, 250 );
        } else if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > 0 && $( window ).scrollTop() > $( ".jumbotron" ).height() )
        {
            if ( !$( "#main-nav" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
            {
                $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
            }
            if ( !$( "#main-nav-box" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
            {
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
            }
            if ( !$( "#scrolltop" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
            {
                $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
            }
            $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
            $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "clicked" );
            $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
            $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
            setTimeout( function ()
            {
                $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
            }, 250 );
        }

        $( window ).scroll( function ()
        {
            if ( !$( "#main-nav-box" ).hasClass( "clicked" ) )
            {
                if ( $( window ).scrollTop() === 0 )
                {
                    if ( !$( "#main-nav" ).hasClass( "scrolledtop" ) )
                    {
                        $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
                        $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                        $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    }
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    setTimeout( function ()
                    {
                        $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                        $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                        $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
                    }, 250 );
                } else if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > 0 && $( window ).scrollTop() > $( ".jumbotron" ).height() )
                {
                    if ( !$( "#main-nav" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                    {
                        $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "in" );
                    }
                    if ( !$( "#main-nav-box" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                    {
                        $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "in" );
                    }
                    if ( !$( "#scrolltop" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                    {
                        $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
                    }
                    $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                    $( "#main-nav" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    $( "#main-nav-box" ).removeClass( "clicked" );
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                    setTimeout( function ()
                    {
                        $( "#main-nav" ).addClass( "in" );
                        $( "#main-nav-box" ).addClass( "in" );
                        $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
                    }, 250 );
                }
            }
            if ( $( window ).scrollTop() === 0 )
            {
                $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
                $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolledtop" );
                setTimeout( function ()
                {
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
                }, 250 );
            } else if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > 0 && $( window ).scrollTop() > $( ".jumbotron" ).height() )
            {
                if ( !$( "#scrolltop" ).hasClass( "scrolled" ) )
                {
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "in" );
                }
                $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "scrolled" );
                $( "#scrolltop" ).removeClass( "scrolledtop" );
                setTimeout( function ()
                {
                    $( "#scrolltop" ).addClass( "in" );
                }, 250 );
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

EDIT2:

Maybe this would help to understand it better
[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xs22hw89/2/)

Comment: y dont u wrap inside `$( window ).resize`;

Comment: if ( $( window ).width() > your breakpoint as integer && target element.hasClass('your class') {
your code here }
you don't need the else statement for this.

Comment: @Iceman how so? the last part?

Comment: @damianocelent if ( $ ( window ).width() > 1024px && $( "body" ).hasClass( "resized" ) ?

Comment: @Zeuthenjr whats not workng?

Comment: @Iceman As I have written in my edit. I don't want it to be one-time fire but constant check like the normal code would, like the if statement on hasclass on a certain tag.

Comment: @Iceman try think of the way CSS style tag works, with the media tag, but in the way of javascript/jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did You tried jQuery [$(window).resize(handler)](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event?

JS Fiddle as example of `.resize()` [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xs22hw89/9/).

Comment: Around the last part?

Comment: Are You asking where to place this event? Basically You write it like this: `$(window).resize(function(){ your_whole_code });`

Comment: Currently i have put this $( window ).resize( function () around my if statement with if ( $( window ).width() > 1024px) it works with the class, but not the jquery, it should be used above 1024px px

Comment: Look at my edit, i have put it in separate, to determind the class, is that how you mean, try put in some code, so it might be easier for me to understand

Comment: First of all there is syntax error - You didn't close scroll event in line 7. Second: It works - button turns red after You scroll down BUT because this code is in resize event wrapper which occurs when you actually resize window, You have to resize window first to bind scroll event. Also You need to unbind scroll event when width > 1000

Comment: Alright, you said I should unbind scroll, i tried just unbind, but it seemed confusing, so i just hit the search button and figured i have to bind first. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xs22hw89/5/) this seems more correct right? it seems like it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120694/discussion-between-kamil-kaminski-and-zeuthenjr).

Answer (score 0):

[`.resize()`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/)

```
$( window ).resize(function(){
  //do the operations here. remeber this code gets recalled evertime the page gets resized)
});
```

Comment: As I said, i'm looking for the a way to turn a certain code of jquery/javascript on and off based on the window size, that way is just call it one-time and not turn it on, like so it uses that code and when it's below a certain size it will turn off and use something else.